# Which version of Ruby should I use with Vim 7.4 on Windows?

Tags: ruby, vim, vim-plugin

I have Ruby version "1.9.3p362 (2012-12-25) [i386-mingw32]" installed. It has `msvcrt-ruby191.dll` in the bin directory. Vim 7.3 could use that, at least `has('ruby')` returned 1. (Some plugins, like LustyJuggler did not work, but I don't know why.) But now with Vim 7.4, it does not work anymore. gvim.exe (in 7.4) references `msvcrt-ruby192.dll` (note the "192"). But even Ruby 1.9.3 has `msvcrt-ruby191.dll` in it, as I said.

I tried renaming `msvcrt-ruby191.dll` to `msvcrt-ruby192.dll` but that resulted in a `LoadError: Incompatible library version`.

I'm surprised I was not able to find people having this problem when I tried to look for solutions.

My goal is to get LustyJuggler to work.

Comment: You shouldn't be surprised, 7.4 is *very* young. This looks like a bug worth reporting.

Answer (score 4):

I read about the issue here http://hynek.me/articles/vim-7-3-on-win32/ and downloaded a version that was compiled for Ruby 2 from http://wyw.dcweb.cn/. Works great.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find any better (or more easy) solution than to edit `gvim.exe` and replace all references to `msvcrt-ruby192.dll` to `msvcrt-ruby191.dll`.
Now it works without any issues.

Comment: I used WinHex hex editor. But this one is proprietary. You could find some free hex editor here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_hex_editors

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

Go there:

http://www.garbagecollect.jp/ruby/mswin32/en/download/release.html

Download ruby-1.9.2-XXX-i386-mswin32.zip package. Extract it somewhere and add the \bin subdirectory of the package to your windows PATH.

Download readline http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/readline.htm, install it. Copy readline5.dll and put it in the \bin directory. Rename it to readline.dll

Rename msvcrt-ruby191.dll to msvcrt-ruby192.dll in the bin directory.

It's an ugly procedure but seems to work for me.